# Open method Implemetantion Force.com IDE

Tags: ide, force.com-ide

Its possible to enable the option 'Hyperlink' in Force.com IDE?. For example to go to method implementation on mouse hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Force.com IDE does not currently support many of the features in Eclipse that you can use for other languages (e.g. Java), including go-to-definition, source formatting, and more. It's possible that it's on the road map, so you might want to follow the [github project](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore) for the IDE.

In the meantime, if you want it *now*, you could always fork the project, hack it in yourself, and then use that personal version. If you did, I'm sure the community would appreciate it if you put in a merge request.

Alternatively, you could use a different IDE. I personally use [Cloud9](https://c9.io/), which is beta, but still incredibly powerful, and does include a go-to-definition feature (note: I'm not affiliated with Cloud9, I just really like their product). You may also find similar features in other IDEs, but I don't have any experience with many other IDEs, so I can't say for sure.